# Were the other Potentials actually humans?

Tags: the-matrix

In The Matrix : Reloaded, when the Kid catches up with Neo right before he leaves Zion, he hands him a gift from one of the Oracle's children: a spoon. Of course, it's a reminder of the lesson learned by Neo in the first movie that...

> "...There is no spoon".

**But how could the spoon be delivered in the real world? Were the other potentials actually humans, and freed at some point? I've never watched Animatrix, so I don't know if it is explained in it...**

Comment: The answer is yes, but not stated directly, rather it's implied

Comment: There's nothing in the Animatrix about the potentials.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive with references to the authorised comic serial and an earlier version of the script. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: `But how could the spoon be delivered in the real world?`  The little boy tells him the answer already.  "There _is_ no spoon."  He gave him _a_ spoon as a symbolic reference to their last meeting, not because it was the same spoon.

Answer (score 5):

### The "potentials" were indeed human

In the film, the fact that Neo is delivered a (hand-made) spoon is a clear indication that some or all of the 'potentials' were in fact humans that were interfacing with The Matrix wirelessly. Spoon Boy (and the others) were most likely returned to Zion when the ships were recalled.

In the Matrix Comic [Broadcast Depth](http://web.archive.org/web/20040603010807/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/sien01.html), we see their ship.

[image]

And in an earlier version of the script, we learn precisely why they're collecting potentials.

> **CYPHER :** *I'm going to let you in on a little secret here. Now don't tell him I told you this, but this ain't the first time Morpheus
>   thought he found the One.*
>
> **NEO :** *Really?*
>
> **CYPHER :** *You bet your ass. It keeps him going. Maybe it keeps all of us going.*
>
> **NEO :** *How many were there?*
>
> **CYPHER :** *Five. Since I've been here.*
>
> **NEO :** *What happened to them?*
>
> **CYPHER :** *Dead. All dead.*
>
> **NEO :** *How?*
>
> **CYPHER :** *Honestly? Morpheus. He got them all amped up believing in bullshit. I watched each of them take on an Agent and I watched
>   each of them die. Little piece of advice: you see an Agent, you do
>   what we do; run. Run your ass off.*

Comment: Didn't some part of that make it into the movie? I *know* that Cyhper says those last two lines to Neo, and I know that the fact that Cypher was himself a previous potential was cut out, but I feel like Cypher gave parts of this speech to Neo in the final cut.

Comment: Yes, in the final cut he says "*So, can I ask you something? Did he tell you why he did it, why you're here? Jesus. What a mind job. So you're here to save the world. What do you say to something like that? A little piece of advice. You see an agent, you do what we do. Run. You run your ass off.*"

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think no.
My reason for this is that I don't think Neo is human. 
We saw how Smith manages to get into Bane's body. Essentially if you re-design the structure of neurons in the brain you can in theory replicate someone else's mind in another body. So I think that's what happens with Neo. He is an AI program stored somewhere or another within the matrix which has been written onto the brain of a certain Mr Anderson.Maybe this happened at birth, maybe it happened when Smith killed him the first time. In any case, I don't think Neo realizes that he is a program as he loves Trinity, yet is surprised by a program speaking of love.The "Ones" before him were presumably the same program written over other peoples brains, or maybe they were variations of the same program, seeing as Neo is the first to rescue Trinity.They may not have even had physical bodies.

As for the other potentials, I think that they are in a similar situation to Neo. They may be programs partially or fully overwriting the brains of humans, or maybe they are programs with no physical bodies, but I highly doubt they have human brain configurations. It is most likely that they are failed attempts at the system trying to write the program for the One onto people brains, and may have half human half machine programmed thought patterns.

Comment: This is an interesting fan-theory but without any sort of evidence to back it up, I fail to see how it answers the question.